# Освобождение динамической памяти перед завершением

Tags: c++, c, утечка-памяти

Почему необходимо избегать утечек памяти в процессе работы программы понятно.
Но зачем нужно освобождать память динамически объявленных переменных перед завершением работы программы?

Единственный ответ, до которого мы с коллегами пришли: чтобы "зомби" (в Linux), если он появится после завершения программы, занимал минимальное место.

В остальных случаях ОС сама подотрет все, что было занято, разве нет?

Какие еще негативные последствия могут возникнуть?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Зомби (в *nix) места в памяти не занимает (в том смысле, который вы в это вкладываете). Он занимает одну запись в стуктуре планировщика в ядре.

А так, да, нормальная современная ОС (в которых почти все пишут) "все подотрет" за процессом. Почти все. С сегментами shared memory проблемы будут, но это в лоб не автоматизируется, поскольку удалять или оставлять -- зависит от сути прикладной задачи.

Если же вдруг будете писать программы под что-то другое (какой-нибудь самодельный монитор для real-time embedded), то может и придется убирать память самому.

Comment: "нормальная современная ОС (в которых почти все пишут)"

т.е. существуют/существовали ОС, где самостоятельное подтирание было действительно важно, да?

Буду Вам очень благодарен, если приведете пример.

Comment: @АлександрРоманов: ДОС? (Наверное.)

Comment: @VladD да, действительно. "Таким образом, программы могут выгружаться из памяти только в порядке, обратном их загрузке, что накладывает ряд ограничений на управление содержимым оперативной памяти. "
http://www.kolasc.net.ru/cdo/programmes/os/322.htm

Answer (score 6):

Смотрите. Никаких причин освобождения **памяти** перед завершением программы, кроме чисто эстетических, нет. Память всё равно вернётся системе после смерти процесса.

Однако, довольно часто объекты в своём деструкторе совершают дополнительные действия. Закрывают транзакцию в базе данных, корректно закрывают онлайн-сессию, сбрасывают изменённые данные на диск и т. п. Таким образом, если такой объект «утечёт», то программа после завершения оставит что-то в некорректном состоянии.

---

Если ваша программа маленькая, вы можете её полностью обозреть, и вы уверены, что кроме утечек памяти ничего плохого от пропущенных деструкторов не случится — можете смело оставлять в конце память.

Но если ваш проект большой, то скорее всего у вас не будет полного обзора того, что какой модуль делает. В такой ситуации лучше придерживаться дисциплинированного подхода и чистить за собой.

Comment: Добавлю свои пять копеек. Это может помочь при поиске других ошибок: вывод `valgrind` куда проще и понятнее, когда устранены "необязательные" ошибки с неосвобожденной памятью, коих можно было избежать.

Comment: @LXA: Угу, valgrind рвёт и мечет на неосвобождённую память.

Answer (score 5):

Перед завершением работы программы нужно убедиться, что разделяемые ресурсы освобождены, например, соединения с базой данных и веб-серверами закрыты. Серверы какое-то время могут считать ваш клиент всё ещё подключенным, что нежелательно. Следует сбросить данные на диск в файлах, если вам есть дело до их содержимого. Если вам всё равно, то можно не закрывать — система справится сама.

Освобождать память обычно ненужно, хоть это и является правилом хорошего тона. Более того, если ваша программа выделила очень много сложных объектов в памяти, и память частично свалилась в своп, то может быть *выгодно не освобождать память*, чтобы не заставлять систему вытаскивать информацию с диска только для того, чтобы её выбросить.

Если вы хотите быстро завершить процесс, то можете аккуратно разрушить объекты, которые хранят ссылки на разделяемые ресурсы, а потом просто убить процесс.

Более того, в идеале программа должна корректно обрабатывать случай убийства процесса в любой момент. Данные при этом не должны быть повреждены. Отработка случая жёсткого убийства процесса без аккуратного освобождения памяти и ресурсов — это важный момент при разработке программ. Из-за этого ваша программа не должна перестать быть работоспособной (например, из-за повреждения конфигурационных файлов).

Comment: Очень интересная идея про своп, спасибо!

Comment: "Отработка случая жёсткого убийства процесса без аккуратного освобождения памяти и ресурсов — это важный момент при разработке программ." А что можно сделать с жёстким сносом? По SIGKILL можно улететь в любой момент, и ничего с этим не поделаешь. Все остальные случаи - ниак не жёсткие, а вполне обрабатываемые.

Comment: @klopp Если есть БД, пользуйтесь транзакциями. Если пишете в файл, то пишите безопасно: сначала во временный файл, потом переименовывайте (если фотошоп умер во время сохранения, работа не должна быть потеряна). Если есть сложное состояние, то может иметь смысл время от времени сохранять его (браузер должен сохранять сессию и восстанавливать её при запуске, как бы он ни умирал). Ну и всё в таком ключе.

Comment: @klopp: Ну, например транзакционная запись в файлы. С оставлением маркеров для подчистки на случай убийства во время записи. То есть (1) записать в новый файл, (2) положить маркер, (3) переименовать старый файл в bak (4) переименовать новый в старый (5) удалить маркер, (6) при старте проверять, остались ли маркеры и корректно закрывать транзакцию. Так никто не делает, в пределах ошибки эксперимента :-)

Comment: Это всё очевидно. Я про то, что KILL всё равно не перехватить и нормальной защиты (как в случае TERM и компании) не предусмотреть. Например, та же shared memory останется, и т.д.

Comment: @klopp Если все программы начнут выполнять хотя бы это "очевидное", то мир станет гораздо лучше...

Comment: Так одно дело - заботиться о СВОИХ ресурсах, и другое - об общественных :) Транзакции, файлы etc - всё это относится к "своим" данным, о которых если не заботишься, то вредишь в первую очередь себе. Забота же об общественном куда менее очевидна, IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

В C++ операторы `delete` и `delete[]`, которыми Вы освобождаете память, вызывают деструкторы объектов. Если в деструкторе есть какая-то логика (например, сериализация), она не сработает, и какие-то данные могут быть потеряны. Замечу так же, что функция `free` деструктор не вызывает, ее задача - освободить память.

Обычно освобождение памяти считается хорошим тоном. Даже если у Вас нет в деструкторах логики сейчас, это не значит, что ее не появится там в будущем (и тогда придется перелопатить весь проект). Если Ваша программа завершается в этом месте сейчас, то это не значит, что в будущем она не будет завершаться гораздо позже (и Вы получите уже значимую утечку памяти). То есть, выполняя очистку памяти, Вы получаете меньше проблем в будущем. Программа становится более расширяемой и поддерживаемой.

Однако, бывает, что память не освобождается специально. Например, в C++ имеется проблема с порядком инициализации/деинициализации статических переменных, которая при выявлении часто решается при помощи синглтона. Такой синглтон должен существовать и после завершения функции `main`, так как после как раз и происходит деинициализация статических переменных. Поэтому он создается при помощи `new` и никогда не освобождается.

Answer (score 2):

1. Код на C работает в таких местах где никакой ОС может вообще не существовать и в помине.
2. Компьютерная память является общим ресурсом, крайне сложным и дорогим в производстве. Не стоит думать что она принадлежит лично Вам. Например в данный момент на хосте откуда я пишу вам это сообщение запущено 106 процессов, написанных другими людьми(физически они все используют DDR за которую заплатил лично я). Представьте что было бы с ними если бы автор каждого из них думал только о себе и не занимался высвобождением памяти, а наоборот пытался схватить её как можно больше будучи одержимым идеей об уникальноси и сверхполезности своей поделки.
3. Момент прекращения использования того или иного ресурса в программе(в частности памяти) может не совпадать с её завершением.

Но если вы пишите какую-то мелкую прикладную программу для популярной ОС в которой при этом еле еле аллокируется 100кБ, то можно конечно понадеется и на ОС и на язык с автоматической сборкой мусора. В принципе ничем страшным это не грозит, если конечно программа внезапно не разрастется до больших размеров и толпы пользователей в придачу. Тогда однозначно стоит начинать более серьезно задумываться о распределении общих ресурсов, в частности и памяти.

Comment: 1. Как правило, там и менеджера памяти не будет, поэтому разговор о new/malloc в таких случаях можно не вести.

2. Вы абсолютно правы. В данном вопросе не идет речь об утечках, накапливаемых во время работы программы. Совершенно согласен, что программа должна потреблять минимум памяти.