# Как указать на первый элемент массива?

Tags: c++, массивы, search

Вопрос до боли простой и я чувствую, что я близко, но втупился в монитор и хожу вокруг да около. Нужно, что б cout выводил "Yes", если это первый элемент и "No", если это какой то другой. Знаю, что в if должно быть по-другому описано, но я просто не знаю как описать это.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

int _size;

cin >> _size;

int* tab = new int [_size];

int number;
for(int i=0;i<_size;i++){
    cin >> number;
    tab[i] = number;
}

for(int i=0; i<_size; i++)
{
    if(tab[0]) 
    cout << "Yes" << endl;
    else cout << "No" << endl;
}
}
```

Comment: Ну, не `if(tab[0])`, а `if (i == 0)`

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное

Comment: А память освобождать кто будет ? Страуструп ?

Comment: @isnullxbh, в данном примере, коль выделяем под массив POD, "освобождение" нужно - если только для эстетики. Тут (http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420070/%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%A1-%D0%A1) хорошее обсуждение.

Comment: @Majestio, хорошо, спасибо, прочту.

Comment: Чисто придирки ради - не используйте первым символом подчеркивание в именах (`_size`) - это зарезервировано за компилятором.

Comment: @Harry Только в глобальном пространстве имен. Более подробно [тут](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.name#3).